# Edible, indoor, winter plants. What lights? (and other advice)

Tags: indoors, light, edible

I don't have any outdoor gardening space and I'd love to grow some edible plants indoors, preferably during the winter when the sunlight is low. I understand I need non pollinated plants, since my apartment is rather low in pollinators. I also want to use grow lights.

1. Am I being silly trying to grow edible plants indoor in the winter?
2. What lights should I get?
3. What kinds of plants can I grow with a good light? I saw [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/edible-plants-for-very-shady-indoor-location), but it's not about lights. People have suggested lettuce, herbs and green onions.
4. Can I just put the plants on a shelf and use a timer with the lights? Do I need something more complicated, e.g. hydroponics?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of light is required for plants to produce food. You will find lights at aquarium web sites . I think it would require a few to several hundred dollars for lights for a 10 square foot shelf.

Answer (score 0):

There are special lights you can buy for growing plants. There are even lights you could use in normal lamps.

Just search for "plant light" on google or amazon.